# Split strings on third white space from the right

Tags: regex, string, r, strsplit

I would like to split a series of strings on the third white space from the right.  The number of white spaces varies among string, but each string has at least three white spaces.  Here are two example strings.

```
strings <- c('abca eagh   ijkl mnop', 'dd1 ss j, ll bb aa')
```

I would like:

```
[1] 'abca', 'eagh   ijkl mnop' 
[2] 'dd1 ss j,', 'll bb aa'
```

The closest I have been able to come is:

```
strsplit(strings, split = "(?<=\\S)(?=\\s(.*)\\s(.*)\\s(.*)$)", perl = TRUE)
```

which returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "abca"         " eagh"        "   ijkl mnop"

[[2]]
[1] "dd1"       " ss"       " j,"       " ll bb aa"
```

I keep thinking the answer should be something like:

```
strsplit(strings, split = "(?<=\\S\\s(.*)\\s(.*)\\s(.*)$)(?=\\s(.*)\\s(.*)\\s(.*)$)", perl = TRUE)
```

However, that returns an error.  Thank you for any advice.  I prefer a solution in base, hopefully one that uses regular expressions.

Comment: Can you reverse your string, then split the reversed string on the third white space from the left (thay may be easier !), and then reverse every substring ?

Comment: Shouldn't the first example `abca eagh{SPACE}{SPACE}{SPACE}ijkl{SPACE}mnop` give you `'abca eagh','  ijkl mnop'` based on your requirements?

Comment: @JonM Perhaps I am not using the term 'white space' correctly.  Sorry about that.  I have included the strings and the desired results.

Comment: So should consecutive whitespace be treated as 'one' whitespace (e.g. 5 spaces in a row should be counted as one whitespace)?

Comment: Yes, 5 consecutive spaces is treated as one white space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the expression:

```
(?=(?>\\s\\S*){3}$)\\s
```

Edit:
Use this expression if you want consecutive whitespace characters to be treated as 'one' whitespace:

```
(?=(?>\\s+\\S*){3}$)\\s
```

It's worth noting that the reason your expression was causing an error is most likely because most regex engines do not permit variable width lookbehinds. In your example that would be the `*` quantifier in the lookbehind breaking the rules.

Got it! Sorry I wasn't 100% on how the strsplit function worked. Try this:

```
strsplit(strings, split = "(?=(?>\\s+\\S*){3}$)\\s", perl = TRUE)
```

Here is an example output:

```
> strings <- c('abca eagh   ijkl mnop', 'dd1 ss j, ll bb aa')
> strsplit(strings, split = "(?=(?>\\s+\\S*){3}$)\\s", perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "abca"             "eagh   ijkl mnop"

[[2]]
[1] "dd1 ss j," "ll bb aa"
```

Comment: I obtain errors with both.  I am using R.  One error concerns \ as an escape character.  Using \\ does not resolve all errors.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer. I have given it R specific syntax.

Comment: You're right! I have updated my answer! I was wrong because I was telling the strsplit function to split at the entire string!

Answer (score 1):

How about using the following regex: `(\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*\s*)(.*)`? See http://regex101.com/r/lI7aA9

Comment: This returns errors.  I am using R which seems to prefer \\ over \.  However, I still obtain errors after using \\.