# String splitting data.table column produces NAs

Tags: r, string, data.table, text-processing

This is my first question on SO so let me know if it can be improved. I am working on a natural language processing project in R and am trying to build a data.table that contains test cases. Here, I build a much simplified example:

```
texts.dt <- data.table(string = c("one", 
                                  "two words",
                                  "three words here",
                                  "four useless words here", 
                                  "five useless meaningless words here", 
                                  "six useless meaningless words here just",
                                  "seven useless meaningless words here just to",
                                  "eigth useless meaningless words here just to fill",
                                  "nine useless meaningless words here just to fill up",
                                  "ten useless meaningless words here just to fill up space"),
                       word.count = 1:10,
                       stop.at.word = c(0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 6, 7, 5))
```

This returns the data.table we will be working on:

```
                                                          string word.count stop.at.word
 1:                                                      one          1            0
 2:                                                two words          2            1
 3:                                         three words here          3            2
 4:                                  four useless words here          4            2
 5:                      five useless meaningless words here          5            4
 6:                  six useless meaningless words here just          6            3
 7:             seven useless meaningless words here just to          7            3
 8:        eigth useless meaningless words here just to fill          8            6
 9:      nine useless meaningless words here just to fill up          9            7
10: ten useless meaningless words here just to fill up space         10            5
```

In the real application, values in the `stop.at.word` column are determined at random (with an upper bound = `word.count` - 1). Also, strings are not ordered by length but that should not make a difference.

The code should add two columns `input`and `output`, where `input`contains the substring from position 1 up to `stop.at.word`and `output` contains the word that follows (single word), like so:

```
>desired_result
                                                          string word.count stop.at.word                                       input
     1:                                                      one          1            0                                            
     2:                                                two words          2            1                                         two
     3:                                         three words here          3            2                                 three words
     4:                                  four useless words here          4            2                                four useless
     5:                      five useless meaningless words here          5            4              five useless meaningless words
     6:                  six useless meaningless words here just          6            2                                 six useless
     7:             seven useless meaningless words here just to          7            3                   seven useless meaningless
     8:        eigth useless meaningless words here just to fill          8            6   eigth useless meaningless words here just
     9:      nine useless meaningless words here just to fill up          9            7 nine useless meaningless words here just to
    10: ten useless meaningless words here just to fill up space         10            5          ten useless meaningless words here
             output
     1:            
     2:       words
     3:        here
     4:       words
     5:        here
     6: meaningless
     7:       words
     8:          to
     9:        fill
    10:        just
```

Unfortunately what I get instead is this:

```
                                                      string word.count stop.at.word input output
 1:                                                      one          1            0             
 2:                                                two words          2            1    NA     NA
 3:                                         three words here          3            2    NA     NA
 4:                                  four useless words here          4            2    NA     NA
 5:                      five useless meaningless words here          5            4    NA     NA
 6:                  six useless meaningless words here just          6            3    NA     NA
 7:             seven useless meaningless words here just to          7            3    NA     NA
 8:        eigth useless meaningless words here just to fill          8            6    NA     NA
 9:      nine useless meaningless words here just to fill up          9            7    NA     NA
10: ten useless meaningless words here just to fill up space         10            5  ten      NA
```

Notice the inconsistent results, with an empty string on row 1 and "ten" returned on row 10.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    texts.dt[, c("input", "output") := .(
        substr(string, 
               1, 
               sapply(gregexpr(" ", string),"[", stop.at.word) - 1),
        substr(string, 
               sapply(gregexpr(" ", string),"[", stop.at.word), 
               sapply(gregexpr(" ", string),"[", stop.at.word + 1) - 1)
    )]
```

I ran many tests and the `substr` instructions work well when I try individual strings in the console, but fail when applied to the data.table.
I suspect I am missing something related to scoping within data.table, but I haven't been using this package for long so I am quite confused.

I would greatly appreciate some assistance.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Minor complaint: Try to make your examples small enough that they don't require horizontal scrolling in the browser.

Comment: @Franck - Sure, I'll do better next time!

Comment: I'm not sure why the other two answers have been deleted..? @ProcrastinatusMaximus

Comment: Also pinging @Frank - I'm voting to undelete both of those - I don't understand why they're gone - afaict both work.

Comment: @eddi My bad. I deleted because my answer was made redundant, which prompted Jaap to do the same. I'll keep mine around, I guess, so as to get his back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably do

```
texts.dt[stop.at.word > 0, c("input","output") := {
  sp = strsplit(string, " ")
  list( 
    mapply(function(p,n) paste(p[seq_len(n)], collapse = " "), sp, stop.at.word),
    mapply(`[`, sp, stop.at.word+1L)
  )
}]

# partial result
head(texts.dt, 4)

                    string word.count stop.at.word        input output
1:                     one          1            0           NA     NA
2:               two words          2            1          two  words
3:        three words here          3            2  three words   here
4: four useless words here          4            2 four useless  words
```

---

Alternately:

```
library(stringi)
texts.dt[stop.at.word > 0, c("input","output") := {
  patt = paste0("((\\w+ ){", stop.at.word-1, "}\\w+) (.*)")
  m    = stri_match(string, regex = patt)
  list(m[, 2], m[, 4])
}]
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to @Frank's `mapply` solution is using `by = 1:nrow(texts.dt)` with `strsplit` and `paste`:

```
library(data.table)
texts.dt[, `:=` (input = paste(strsplit(string, ' ')[[1]][1:stop.at.word][stop.at.word>0],
                               collapse = " "),
                 output = strsplit(string, ' ')[[1]][stop.at.word + 1]),
         by = 1:nrow(texts.dt)]
```

which gives:

```
> texts.dt
                                                      string word.count stop.at.word                                       input output
 1:                                                      one          1            0                                                one
 2:                                                two words          2            1                                         two  words
 3:                                         three words here          3            2                                 three words   here
 4:                                  four useless words here          4            2                                four useless  words
 5:                      five useless meaningless words here          5            4              five useless meaningless words   here
 6:                  six useless meaningless words here just          6            3                     six useless meaningless  words
 7:             seven useless meaningless words here just to          7            3                   seven useless meaningless  words
 8:        eigth useless meaningless words here just to fill          8            6   eigth useless meaningless words here just     to
 9:      nine useless meaningless words here just to fill up          9            7 nine useless meaningless words here just to   fill
10: ten useless meaningless words here just to fill up space         10            5          ten useless meaningless words here   just
```

Instead of using `[[1]]` you could also wrap the `strsplit` in `unlist` as follows: `unlist(strsplit(string, ' '))` (instead of `strsplit(string, ' ')[[1]]`). This will give you the same result.

---

Two other options:

**1)** with the *stringi* package:

```
library(stringi)
texts.dt[, `:=`(input = paste(stri_extract_all_words(string[stop.at.word>0],
                                                     simplify = TRUE)[1:stop.at.word],
                              collapse = " "),
                output = stri_extract_all_words(string[stop.at.word>0],
                                                simplify = TRUE)[stop.at.word+1]),
         1:nrow(texts.dt)]
```

**2)** or an adaptation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21904586/2204410):

```
texts.dt[stop.at.word>0, 
         c('input','output') := tstrsplit(string, 
                                          split = paste0("(?=(?>\\s+\\S*){",
                                                         word.count - stop.at.word,
                                                         "}$)\\s"), 
                                          perl = TRUE)
         ][, output := sub('(\\w+).*','\\1',output)]
```

which both give:

```
> texts.dt
                                                      string word.count stop.at.word                                       input output
 1:                                                      one          1            0                                          NA     NA
 2:                                                two words          2            1                                         two  words
 3:                                         three words here          3            2                                 three words   here
 4:                                  four useless words here          4            2                                four useless  words
 5:                      five useless meaningless words here          5            4              five useless meaningless words   here
 6:                  six useless meaningless words here just          6            3                     six useless meaningless  words
 7:             seven useless meaningless words here just to          7            3                   seven useless meaningless  words
 8:        eigth useless meaningless words here just to fill          8            6   eigth useless meaningless words here just     to
 9:      nine useless meaningless words here just to fill up          9            7 nine useless meaningless words here just to   fill
10: ten useless meaningless words here just to fill up space         10            5          ten useless meaningless words here   just
```

Comment: The correct adaptation would use `word.count - stop.at.word` or similar instead of `stop.at.word`

Answer (score 5):

```
dt[, `:=`(input  = sub(paste0('((\\s*\\w+){', stop.at.word, '}).*'), '\\1', string),
          output = sub(paste0('(\\s*\\w+){', stop.at.word, '}\\s*(\\w+).*'), '\\2', string))
   , by = stop.at.word][]
#                                                      string word.count stop.at.word
# 1:                                                      one          1            0
# 2:                                                two words          2            1
# 3:                                         three words here          3            2
# 4:                                  four useless words here          4            2
# 5:                      five useless meaningless words here          5            4
# 6:                  six useless meaningless words here just          6            3
# 7:             seven useless meaningless words here just to          7            3
# 8:        eigth useless meaningless words here just to fill          8            6
# 9:      nine useless meaningless words here just to fill up          9            7
#10: ten useless meaningless words here just to fill up space         10            5
#                                          input output
# 1:                                                one
# 2:                                         two  words
# 3:                                 three words   here
# 4:                                four useless  words
# 5:              five useless meaningless words   here
# 6:                     six useless meaningless  words
# 7:                   seven useless meaningless  words
# 8:   eigth useless meaningless words here just     to
# 9: nine useless meaningless words here just to   fill
#10:          ten useless meaningless words here   just
```

I'm not sure I understand the logic for `output` being nothing for first line, but the trivial fix, if indeed needed, is left to OP.

Comment: @eddi Thanks and you are right, there is no logic; I should have left "one" in the output column. But when I apply it to my large data.frame, your solution returns an error: `
`Error in sub(paste0("((\\s*\\w+){", stop.at.word, "}).*"), "\\1", string) : 
  invalid regular expression '((\s*\w+){308}).*', reason 'Invalid contents of {}`
Any ideas?

Comment: @Luc Apparently there are limits on finite regex quantifiers. Maybe you're hitting it http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=649090

Comment: Apparently, the limit is `255`. Try `x = paste(rep("A", 400), collapse=""); grep("A{256}", x)`

Comment: @LucFrachon if you add `perl = TRUE` to the `sub`, you'll be able to go up to 65K